# Fibonacci in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

This shows no errors but when run with an input 0 the output it shows is    "   0 1 1 b - " 
where s the out put should be like " 0 1 1 2 3 5 ....... "  Below is the code

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
cons dw 1
num db 0
result db 10 dup('$'),0ah,0dh
.code
input proc ;Input procedure Starts
      xor ax,ax
      xor bx,bx
      xor cx,cx
      xor dx,dx
      mov cx,-1
tag1:
      mov ah,01
      int 21h
      mov bl,al
      sub bx,48
      push bx
      inc cx
      cmp al,0dh
      jne tag1
      pop bx
tag2:
      pop bx
      mov ax,cons
      mul bx
      add num,al
      mov ax,cons
      mov dx,10
      mul dx
      mov cons,ax
      loop tag2
      ret
input endP  ; Input procedure Ends
fabio proc  ; Procedure to find out the sequence and print it
      mov ax,0
      mov bx,0
      mov cx,5
      mov dx,0
      mov al,num
      mov bl,num
      add bx,1
      add ax,48
      add bx,48
      mov dx,ax
      mov ah,02
      int 21h    ; printing 1 of the 2 first numbers
      mov dx,0
      mov dx,bx
      mov ah,02
      int 21h
      mov al,num
      mov bl,num
      add bx,1
tag4:
      add al,bl ; the problem lies from somewhere here to the code below
      mov num,al
      mov bl,al
      add al,1
      mov dx,0
      add num,48
      mov dl,num
      mov ah,02
      int 21h
      loop tag4
      ret
fabio endP
proc main
      mov ax,@data
      mov ds,ax
      call input
      call fabio
      mov ax,4c00h
      int 21h
end main
main endP
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger, use better label names and add comments.

Answer (score 0):

According to Ralph Brown's Interrupt List ( http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm ); due to "not officially documented" behaviour the DOS "write character to STDOUT" function returns the last character output in AL.

This would corrupt whatever you're using AL for if you're not expecting it.

*Note: As far as I can tell this is the bug you're looking for; but when this bug is fixed your code would still be wrong due to other bugs, in addition to being "less than ideal" (superfluous instructions, etc). If your code was written in assembly (e.g. with comments, etc) instead of being written in nonsense (with magic values and no comments) most of these other problems wouldn't be there (you would've noticed and fixed most of them while writing the original code) and I would've pointed out any that remained.*